# Eclipse CDT static resources under build folder

Tags: build-process, eclipse-cdt

I'm building a C++ project under Eclipse and my release folder should include a static sub-folder with some files inside it, those are required by executable during runtime. The problem is that this folder is automatically deleted before every build - entire release folder is completely wiped out and I'm losing all the files inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is simple - need to place rm.exe from mingw utilites on path and Eclipse will delete only specific build files instead of removing entire release folder.